# Spring JDBC simple example

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am new to Spring and making a simple application using JDBC which reads the records from database and displays on screen.

```
package jdbcexample;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "Beans.xml");
    StudentJDBCTemplate studentjdbctemplate = (StudentJDBCTemplate) context
            .getBean("studentjdbctemplate");
    System.out.println("Listing Reocrds : ");
    List<Student> students = studentjdbctemplate.listStudents();
    for (Student record : students)
        System.out.println("id : " + record.getId() + " name : "
                + record.getName() + " password : " + record.getPassword());

}

}
```

This is my Bean.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://locallhost:3306/TEST" />
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="studentjdbctemplate" class="jdbcexample.StudentJDBCTemplate">
    <property name="datasource" ref="datasource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

All referenced Java files and XML file are in same folder but I am still getting this error. Can you please help me fix this?

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at jdbcexample.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: You need to keep Beans.xml in classpath.

Comment: please accept one of the answer below so that other having same problem can find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved Beans.xml to src folder and the program ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here in exception trace `class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Means Beans.xml is missing from the classpath and hence you see the exception. Make sure Beans.xml is in the classpath and it would work fine.

Comment: How can I include it in classpath ?

Comment: Either use CLASSPATH environment variable to have directory where Beans.xml resides or pass on it with -cp option with java command like -cp "/a/b/c" where Beans.xml resides in "c" directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this article.](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/maven-spring-mvc-hibernate-sitemesh-hello-world-project.html)
This will help you setup a basic MAVEN Spring MVC HIbernate Sitemesh project

What you are missing here is a `file not found` that is Beans.xml.

YOu define this class in web.xml you can either do this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Beans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and you need to do this

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/application-config.xml,
            /WEB-INF/Beans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I hope this should work for you

Comment: I am not using MVC framework. I am making simple Spring application using jdbc.